# How to search for 2 values in the same field with codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a database field containing keyword ids ["1","2","3","4","5","6"] and I want to search for several of these ids in the same field.

Here is the idea of what I would like to achieve:

```
$tags[] = "\"1\"";

$tags[] = "\"2\"";

$query = $this->db->like(array('ids_keywords' => $tags[0], 'ids_keywords' => $tags[1]));
```

The problem here is that codeigniter only executes the last request instead of both because the search field is same.

What would be the best solution to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but this seems to search with a OR condition and returns all fields containing "1" OR "2". I need to search for "1" AND "2" in the same field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
$arrTags = [1,2];
$this->db->group_start()
foreach($arrTags AS $strTag)
{
    $this->db->like(ids_keywords, '"'.$strTag.'"');

}
$this->db->group_end();
```

Comment: Thanks sintakonte !!

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own clauses:

```
$where = "ids_keywords='1' AND ids_keywords='2' OR ids_keywords='3'";

$this->db->where($where);
```

For safe query use question mark(?)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE ids_keywords = ? AND ids_keywords = ? AND ids_keywords = ?";
   $this->db->query($sql, array(1, 2, 3));
```

In the above example, the question mark(?) will be replaced by the array in the second parameter of query() function. The main advantage of building query this way is that the values are automatically escaped which produce safe queries. CodeIgniter engine does it for you automatically.

Comment: Thx, but in this case i'm not protecting the query for SQL injection